# Tendermint to Bigchaindb connection

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, bigchaindb, tendermint

is there any solution for this connection error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was Tendermint running (in the background or maybe in the foreground in another Terminal window)? If not, then that would explain it.

There are instructions at http://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/latest/simple-network-setup.html (which also work for a single-node "network").